# Como obter o texto da linha em que o cursor esta posicionado?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Tenho um textbox, e necessito obter o conteúdo da linha onde o cursor está posicionado. 
Por exemplo, estou na terceira linha do textbox(cursor posicionado nela), gostaria de obter o conteúdo dessa linha. Agradeço desde já...

Comment: É Windows Forms?

Comment: É Windows Forms sim

Comment: @LocalHost ñ entendi muito bem o q vc deseja, não pode usar a opção `Copiar`? Vc poderia tbm nos mostrar como esta seu código e como esta tentando fazer?

Comment: Por exemplo, estou na terceira linha do textbox, movimentando com a seta para cima ou para baixo, e se por exemplo eu estiver nessa terceira linha(cursor posicionado nela), gostaria de obter o conteúdo dessa linha, entende?

Comment: A questão principal que não estou conseguindo fazer, é obter o conteúdo da linha na qual esta sobre foco

Comment: @LocalHost sim acho q entendi, vc deseja obter todo o conteúdo da linha onde está posicionada a barrinha vertical **|** ou apenas uma palavra?

Comment: Isso, todo o conteúdo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que você tenha um `TextBox` com a propriedade `MultLine` habilitada para `true`.

Sendo assim, para obter o conteúdo da linha onde esta posicionada a barra vertical **|** basta usar este método que criei `PegaConteudoDaLinhaAtual()`, veja:

```
string PegaConteudoDaLinhaAtual(TextBox textBox)
{            
    var textoDaLinha = textBox.Lines[textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox.SelectionStart)].ToString();
    return textoDaLinha;           
}
```

Aqui é a implementação dele no clique do botão:

```
private void btnPega_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    MessageBox.Show(PegaConteudoDaLinhaAtual(textBox1));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, Valeuzão mesmo. Ajudou bastante :)